# FileNames becomes extremely slow when there are large number of files under a directory

Tags: performance-tuning, files-and-directories

I have a directory on my portable hard drive, with around 350000 files under it (there is no subdirectory, only files). I want to get all the file dirs so use

```
 filedirs=FileNames["*",mydir]
```

However, the code above run for more than 1 hour and still not return a result. Why is `FileNames` so slow? What should I do?

I'm using Mathematica 12.0 on my Win10.

---

The problem is bypassed by running `tree dir /f /a >outputtxt` on win10's cmd window, as suggested by @mikado. The size of outputtxt is only ~20M and it takes only several minites to get result. I still don't understand why `FileNames` will take astonishing time to run.

Comment: Two ideas come to mind: 1) the OS is just overloaded by having so many files in a single flat structure 2) Mathematica's struggling to keep 350000 file name strings in memory. Both are plausible and both have a simple solution: use folders.

Comment: emmm........how to use folders? I have to manully copy and move thousands of files?@b3m2a1

Comment: Use an external tool to write the names to file, then get Mathematica to read the file

Comment: good idea! In windows cmd run `tree dir /f /a >outputtxt` I get the filename list. @mikado

Comment: @b3m2a1 In my experience, it's not Mathathematica that struggles from having to handle these strings. I've seen this problem as well and I think it's the OS or the interface between the two.

Comment: What time does it take to run for on command prompt. For my 11000 files it takes around 10 seconds. Redirect to file is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Under windows system this is the way to get huge number of filenames under a directory:

```
filenamesFast[dir_]:=
Module[{txtname="\\temp-alldirs.txt"},
Run["dir \""<>dir<>"\" /b >\""<>dir<>txtname<>"\""];
(dir<>#)&/@StringSplit[Import[dir<>txtname],"\n"]
]
```

Comment: This is very useful. If you use `Import[..., "List"]`, you don't need to do the `StringSplit` step. I also recommend using `FileNameJoin` instead of joining file paths with `StringJoin`.